# How to read a file char by char in C++?

Tags: c++

I have to read a text word by word, and save every word in an array, but i have to exclude commas, fullstops etc.

I guess the best option is to read the file char by char so i can exclude every non-letter char during the reading phase.
I don't really understand the input from file system logically my code isnt working proprelly

```
void readFile(  )
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open ("text.txt");
    string word;
    char x;
    word.clear();
    while (x != '^') // ^ is the last character in the text, maybe i need a better system to stop this while
    {
        x = file.get();

        if ( x != ' ' || x != ',' || x != '^' || x != '.' )
        {
            word = word + x;
        }
        else
        {
        cout << word << endl;
        word.clear();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is it not working properly? Is the file actually open? does it contain anything? You should initialize `x` to a start value and then do the while check.

Comment: Setting the last character to ^ and using that is quite a smell. `ifstream::get(char&)` returns a boolean that goes false when the file is at it's end, so simply go with `while(file.get(x))`. That said, your code "not working properly" is not a question. State what it actually does (at least what is printed on the console), and on what input.

Comment: @Aziuth `get` returns an `ifstream&` instead of `bool`. Your sentence can be made more accurate by changing the sentence to “a call to `get` is a *contextually converted expression* to `bool` and can be used as a condition in `while` statements.” Never mind, I am just being pedantic ;-)

Comment: @L.F. Nah, I actually never bothered to check and assumed that it was bool since that worked for me. Knowing how it actually works is worth something, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I would suggest doing some research on regular expressions (regex) and while loops involving the term EOF (End Of File). You can use the regex to quickly match against any non alpha-numeric character.

Comment: Regexes are way overkill here.

Comment: What is `x != '^'` on the first iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the fact you are using `get()` in a bad way (you need to pass the char as argument), you should rather read directly word by word than character by character as you do.

The `operator>>()` in `std::ifstream` was overloaded for reading word by word.

You can find below an example that does what you want by reading word by word:

**Example (word by word)**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c);

int main()
{
    std::string file_path("text.txt");
    std::ifstream in_s(file_path);

    std::vector <std::string> content;

    if(in_s)
    {
        std::string word;
        while(in_s >> word)
        {
            // handle fullstops
            while(word.find('.') != std::string::npos)
            {
                word.replace(word.find("."), 1, " ");
            }
            // handle commas
            while(word.find(',') != std::string::npos)
            {
                word.replace(word.find(","), 1, " ");
            }

            for(std::string w : split(word, ' '))
                content.push_back(w);
        }

        in_s.close();
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Could not open: " + file_path << std::endl;

    for(std::string word : content)
        std::cout << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string & s, char c)
{
    std::vector<std::string> splitted;

    std::string word;
    for(char ch : s)
    {
        if((ch == c) && (!word.empty()))
        {
            splitted.push_back(word);
            word.clear();
        }
        else
            word += ch;
    }
    if(!word.empty())
        splitted.push_back(word);

    return splitted;
}
```

---

**Upgrade by reading line by line**

Of course, using that code, we can easily see that reading line by line would be more efficient.
To do this, you just have to replace:

```
while(in_s >> word)
```

By:

```
while(getline(in_s, word)) // Of course you can change the variable name 'word' by 'line' for a better consistency and readability.
```

---

If you really want to read character by character, you can check the end of the file by using the method `eof()` from your `ifstream`.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing the file.open() fails - and you do not handle that case properly.
One way to handle that situation would be:

```
file.open ("text.txt");
if (!file) {
  std::cout << "error reading text.txt" << std::endl;
}
```

Besides that, you are probably better off reading the file one line at a time via:
    [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Answer (score 0):

if you set x to be a string it will read string sized parts of your file. you can also get the entire line then split it based on commas, spaces, etc...
hope this helps